# ActiveModel table - has_many but one default record

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I would like to select (do a join) to a record which has a column with boolean true and the table has_many records for this specific user.

For example, User model has_many PhoneNumbers and from the many PhoneNumbers he has a default phone number.

Is it possible to do it that way?

Thank you. :)

Comment: Do you mean like getting the default phone number for users by using JOIN?

Comment: Yes. That's what i meant.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say:

`User(:id, :first_name, :last_name)`

`PhoneNumber(:id, :user_id, :value, :is_default)`

where `:is_default` is the boolean field saying whether it's the default phone number of user or not. Then you can do it this way:

`@users = User.joins(:phone_numbers).where('phone_numbers.is_default IS TRUE').select('users.*, phone_numbers.value AS phone_number')`

Then you may do `@users.first.phone_number` to get the default phone number of the first user.

Hope this would help!